# start css effect from x px / x% width count from left to y px / y % count from right

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, jquery-animate, core-animation

How can I apply my css from width of 80% to width of 60% count from right? I would like to have reveal text effect in css that I set up but it start from 0px count from left to 1500px to right. How can I change my code so the effect is from 40% of width counted from left to right, the black opacity: 0.5 area will start from middle of page to shrink to small area to right direction?

````
.text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: reveal;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}```


[codepen](https://codepen.io/imio24/pen/zYdBOOM)
````

Comment: use `transform-origin: 100%;` or `transform-origin: right;`.

Comment: under `@keyframes reveal`?